# Bash script for grepping string and placing them into array

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm looking way to make bash script that greps output of command and place strings into array and be able to randomly select 1 string from the array for example every minute and place it as variable, time for randomly selecting needs to be configurable.

```
Command output:
string
string2
string3
```

Place of all these strings into array and randomly select one of them and place it as variable

```
desired result:
strings -> array <- randomly selecting from array every 1 minute and placing string selected as variable for further use
```

Comment: This is crying out for some example input together with corresponding desired output.

Comment: Selecting randomly every for example 1 minute, so this 1 minute is the time

Comment: randomly selecting happens every minute so next minute random string is selected again, from the array where those string above are stored

Comment: capture all at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you can use `readarray` with command substitution to capture newline-separated outputs into an array; for exmaple:

```
readarray -t outputs < <(seq 10)
```

Where I've used `seq 10` to produce some output. This results in:

```
$ declare -p outputs
declare -a outputs='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="6" [6]="7" [7]="8" [8]="9" [9]="10")'
```

To pseudorandomly select one of those elements every minute:

```
while :
do
  element=$(( RANDOM % ${#outputs[@]} ))
  var=${outputs[$element]}
  sleep 60
done
```

Noting that bash arrays start at index zero, the `$(( ))` arithemtic says to use the value of `$RANDOM` modulo the number of elements in the `outputs` array.

Comment: Nice and simple solution, thanks!